# Reading materials on Lee-Yang zeroes for spin systems with quenched disorder

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, ising-model, spin-models, disorder

I am trying to have a deeper understanding of the Lee-Yang zeros for spin systems with quenched disorder. So far I have read Section 3.2 of Itzykson-Drouffe which covers the concept for Ising model. Any pointer would be appreciated.

Comment: I suspect Mussardo has written about them.

Comment: You may find this paper interesting, https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.02379, and references there in.

Comment: @ConnorBehan, could you elaborate on that? Are you referring to any specific paper?